# Error when using generics when trying to implement Iterable in Java

Tags: java, generics, iterator, iterable

Can anyone explain why I am getting this error?

Here is a stack class I implemented using a doubly linked list:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Stack<Item> implements Iterable<Item>{

private Node first;
private int N;

private class Node{
    private Node next;
    private Node prev;
    private Item item;
}

public Iterator<Item> iterator(){
    return new ReverseIterator<Item>();
}    

private class ReverseIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item>{
    private Node x;

    private ReverseIterator(){
        if (first != null)
           x = first.prev;
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        return x != null;
    }

    public Item next(){
        Item i = x.item;
        x = x.prev;
        return i;
    }

    public void remove(){
    }
}

public void push(Item i){
    if (isEmpty()){
        first = new Node();
        first.item = i;
        first.next = first;
        first.prev = first;
    }
    else{
        Node x = new Node();
        x.item = i;
        x.next = first;
        x.prev = first.prev;
        first.prev.next = x;
        first.prev = x;
    }
    N++;
}

public Item pop(){
    assert !isEmpty() : "Stack is empty";

    Item i = first.prev.item;
    if (N == 1)
        first = null;
    else{
        first.prev.prev.next = first;
        first.prev = first.prev.prev;
    }

    N--;    
    return i;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return N == 0;
}

public int size(){
    return N;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

}
}
```

The compiler says there's an error in `Item i = x.item;`, expected Item, found Item. The solution was to replace `ReverseIterator<Item>` with `ReverseIterator`. Can someone explain why I got the error I did by adding `<Item>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you used the same name for the type variable (`Item`) does not mean that it represents the same generic type.

If you declare a nested class `N<T>`, inside a generic class `C<T>`, the `T` from `C<T>` is effectively hidden from the body of `N<T>`.  It is exactly the same principle as declaring a class level field called `x` and declaring a method parameter in that class, also called `x`.  Your innermost declaring scope hides anything from the outside.

If `ReverseIterator` were a *static* nested class, you would be obliged to add the `<Item>` to its declaration, because instances of it would not have an enclosing instance of `Stack<Item>`.  And the same error would result, even though in this case there would be no hiding going on.  In fact, you would need to add the type variable to `Node` as well.

Comment: Snap! And I think you describe it better.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
private class ReverseIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item>{
```

Here you are defining an inner class dealing with objects of type `Item` but this type is not the same type as the `Item` type of the enclosing `Stack` class. As a result, when you do the `Item i = x.item;` `x.item` is of type `Stack.Item` (sort of) while `i` is of type `Stack.ReverseIterator.Item`.

You have two options, one is to do as you have done and make the inner class use the same `Item` type as the outer or you could make the inner class `static` and hold its own inner `Item` type (although in this case I would recommend using a different name for the inner type or you will find yourself confused again).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Stack<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

    private Node first;
    private int N;

    private class Node {
        private Node next;
        private Node prev;
        private Item item;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
        return new ReverseIterator();
    }

    private class ReverseIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
        private Node x;

        private ReverseIterator() {
            if (first != null) {
                x = first.prev;
            }
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return x != null;
        }

        public Item next() {
            Item i = x.item;
            x = x.prev;
            return i;
        }

        public void remove() {
        }
    }

    public void push(final Item i) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            first = new Node();
            first.item = i;
            first.next = first;
            first.prev = first;
        } else {
            Node x = new Node();
            x.item = i;
            x.next = first;
            x.prev = first.prev;
            first.prev.next = x;
            first.prev = x;
        }
        N++;
    }

    public Item pop() {
        assert !isEmpty() : "Stack is empty";

        Item i = first.prev.item;
        if (N == 1) {
            first = null;
        } else {
            first.prev.prev.next = first;
            first.prev = first.prev.prev;
        }

        N--;
        return i;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return N == 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return N;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

    }
}
```